# Find if $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(an)!}{{(n!)}^{b}}$ converges depending on $a, b$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Find if $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(an)!}{{(n!)}^{b}}$   converges depending on the values of parameters $a$ and $b$.

I tried to use the ratio test:

\begin{align}
R &=  \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_n}{x_{n+1}}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(an)!}{{(n!)}^{b}} \frac{{((n+1)!)}^{b}}{(a(n+1))!}\\
& = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{{((n+1)!)}^{b}}{{(n!)}^{b}} \frac{(an)!}{(a(n+1))!}\\
& = \lim_{n\to\infty}{(n+1)}^{b}\frac{(an)!}{(an+a)!}\\
& = \lim_{n\to\infty}{(n+1)}^{b}\frac{1}{(an+1)(an+2)\dots(an+a)}\\
& = \lim_{n\to\infty}{(n)}^b(1 + \frac{1}{n})^{b}\frac{1}{n^{a}(a+\frac1{n})(a+\frac2{n})\dots(a+\frac{a}{n})}
\end{align}

From here I'm not sure how to proceed. Can I say that depending on the value of $n^{(b-a)}$  if $b\ge a$, $R\le  1$ if $b\le a$ and $R=1$ if $a=b$?

Then for $R\ge 1$ it converges, for $R\le 1$ it diverges.

Is this correct? And what do I do when $R = 1$?

Edit: I tried to use Stirling's formula, but I still couldn't reach a concrete result.

Comment: Stirling's formula could be useful here.

Comment: If I use Stirling's formula I reach the result that R = limit of $n^{1 -n(2+b)+b} $ and some values that seem to be less important.

Comment: Any help, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I'm assuming a is an integer greater than or equal to 0.

You can go ahead and finish the limit:

$R=(\lim_{n \to \infty}n^{b-a})(\lim_{n \to \infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^b)(\lim_{n \to \infty}(\frac{1}{(a+\frac1{n})(a+\frac2{n})\dots(a+\frac{a}{n})}))$

For the middle limit, you can bring the middle limit inside... giving you $1^b=1$

Similarly the last limit is $\frac{1}{a^a}$

$R = \frac{\lim_{n \to \infty}n^{b-a}}{a^a}$

If $b<a$, $R<1$ so it diverges

If $b>a$, $R > 1$, so it converges

If $b=a$ and $a>1$ then $R<1$ so it diverges

For $b=a=1$, plug them into the original formula for the series.

You get
$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(n)!}{{(n!)}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(1)$ which diverges.

For $b=a=0$, substitute directly again to get $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(1)$ which diverges.

Comment: Thank you a lot!

Comment: You're welcome.